# Pop Up Message when the Stock Levels reach the Critical Level

Tags: vba, ms-access, popup, message

The Basic Function of this is that when you Log in to the system and when on load of the Main Menu it should show a message if certain Products have reached the critical level and when you press yes it should redirect to the form where it shows a detailed view.

In this Case the Quantity in hand is "QTY" and Critical Level is "ROQ" (Field names in the tblProduct)

```
    Dim Alert As Integer

    Dim rsAlert As New Adodb.Recordset

    rsAlert.Open "select * from tblproduct , CurrentProject.Connection"

    Alert = DCount("[qty]", "[tblProduct]", " [ROQ]  <= Qty and =0")

    If Alert = 0 Then

    Exit Sub

    Else

     If MsgBox("This/These " & Alert & " product/products have reached their critical levels" & _
     vbCrLf & vbCrLf & "Would you like to see these now?", _
     vbYesNo, "Alert...") = vbYes Then

    DoCmd.Minimize
    DoCmd.OpenForm "frmAlerts", acNormal
    Else
        Exit Sub
    End If
    End If

    End Sub
```

The error I get is that when load my menu menu it doesn't show the number of products which are under the critical level ! If anyone can help it would be a Great Help!

This has been done in Microsoft Access.

Comment: What exactly is "a certain mistake in my coding"? Can you edit the question to include the incorrect and expected behavior?

Comment: @comintern I made corrections !

Answer (score 0):

Further to my comment this is a not going to work. Create a list box and populate it with the stock shortages, something like this;

```
Dim rsAlert         As Recordset
Dim sSql            As String

sSql = "SELECT ProductID, Description, OtherFields, GoHere FROM tblproduct WHERE ROQ >= QTY AND ROQ > 0"

Set rsAlert = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset(sSql, dbOpenSnapshot)

If Not rsAlert.EOF Then                    'There are records (shortages) so unhide and poulate the list box (called lstShortageListBox)
    Me.lstShortageListBox.Visible = True
    Me.lstShortageListBox.RowSource = sSql
Else

    Me.lstShortageListBox.Visible = False
End If

' Tidy Up
rsAlert.Close
Set rsAlert = Nothing
```

Obviously make sure that the recordsets criteria are correct - I've made some guesses about that bit.